# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can’t connect to local MySQL server through socket ‘/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock’ (2)

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, nginx, mariadb

Hello I've a major issue here that the server diskspace got full days ago, then all services turned off
I managed to clear some space and have 48GB free space, but **the issue I face now is that  I can't start Apache, MariaDB, and nginx services**

Every time I start Apache, MariaDB, or nginx it turns off and I get an error in the email:

> Can't connect to MySQL localhost
> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

```
service mysql restart
```

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
root/home/admin# systemctl status mysql.service
```

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-07-21 23:47:07 CEST; 1mi>
    Process: 5983 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=e>

Jul 21 23:47:07 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, r>
Jul 21 23:47:07 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jul 21 23:47:07 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated t>
Jul 21 23:47:07 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit>
Jul 21 23:47:07 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Then I tried

`systemctl status mariadb.service`

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of mariadb.servic>
● mariadb.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit mariadb.service is masked.)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
             └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
     Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2023-07-21 23:42:42 CEST; 26min ago
   Main PID: 826 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Jul 21 23:42:42 mariadbd[826]: 2023-07-21 23:42:42 0 [Note] InnoDB:>
Jul 21 23:42:42 mariadbd[826]: 2023-07-21 23:42:42 0 [Note] InnoDB:>
Jul 21 23:42:42 mariadbd[826]: 2023-07-21 23:42:42 0 [Note] InnoDB:>
Jul 21 23:42:42 mariadbd[826]: 2023-07-21 23:42:42 0 [Note] InnoDB:>
Jul 21 23:42:42 mariadbd[826]: 2023-07-21 23:42:42 0 [Note] InnoDB:>
Jul 21 23:42:42 mariadbd[826]: 2023-07-21 23:42:42 0 [Note] InnoDB:>
Jul 21 23:42:42 mariadbd[826]: 2023-07-21 23:42:42 0 [Note] InnoDB:>
Jul 21 23:42:42 mariadbd[826]: 2023-07-21 23:42:42 0 [Note] /usr/sb>
Jul 21 23:42:42 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Succeeded.
Jul 21 23:42:42 systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.5.21 database server.
lines 1-19/19 (END)...skipping...
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of mariadb.servic>
● mariadb.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit mariadb.service is masked.)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
             └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
     Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2023-07-21 23:42:42 CEST; 26min ago
   Main PID: 826 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Jul 21 23:42:42 mariadbd[826]: 2023-07-21 23:42:42 0 [Note] InnoDB:>
Jul 21 23:42:42 mariadbd[826]: 2023-07-21 23:42:42 0 [Note] InnoDB:>
Jul 21 23:42:42 mariadbd[826]: 2023-07-21 23:42:42 0 [Note] InnoDB:>
Jul 21 23:42:42 mariadbd[826]: 2023-07-21 23:42:42 0 [Note] InnoDB:>
Jul 21 23:42:42 mariadbd[826]: 2023-07-21 23:42:42 0 [Note] InnoDB:>
Jul 21 23:42:42 mariadbd[826]: 2023-07-21 23:42:42 0 [Note] InnoDB:>
Jul 21 23:42:42 mariadbd[826]: 2023-07-21 23:42:42 0 [Note] InnoDB:>
Jul 21 23:42:42 mariadbd[826]: 2023-07-21 23:42:42 0 [Note] /usr/sb>
Jul 21 23:42:42 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Succeeded.
Jul 21 23:42:42 systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.5.21 database server.
```

nginx :

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/log/apache2/domains/domain.com.error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I checked the space now

```
root: df -h
```

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev 1.9G 0 1.9G 0% /dev
tmpfs 383M 892K 382M 1% /run
/dev/sda1 75G 25G 48G 34% /
tmpfs 1.9G 0 1.9G 0% /dev/shm
tmpfs 5.0M 0 5.0M 0% /run/lock
tmpfs 1.9G 0 1.9G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15 61M 2.7M 58M 5% /boot/efi
tmpfs 383M 0 383M 0% /run/user/1000
```

checked the memory too

```
root# free -h
```

```
total used free shared buff/cache available
Mem: 3.7Gi 294Mi 2.5Gi 11Mi 979Mi 3.2Gi
Swap: 0B 0B 0B
```

I also tried

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

```
[Sat Jul 22 00:28:29.156692 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2027:tid 1396530985873 92] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sat Jul 22 00:29:26.864621 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4398:tid 1398630996472 32] AH00489: Apache/2.4.57 (Ubuntu) configured – resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 22 00:29:26.864729 2023] [core:notice] [pid 4398:tid 139863099647232] A H00094: Command line: ‘/usr/sbin/apache2’
[Sat Jul 22 00:29:27.069516 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4398:tid 1398630996472 32] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sat Jul 22 00:29:33.810002 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4946:tid 1401744768053 76] AH00489: Apache/2.4.57 (Ubuntu) configured – resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 22 00:29:33.810084 2023] [core:notice] [pid 4946:tid 140174476805376] A H00094: Command line: ‘/usr/sbin/apache2’
[Sat Jul 22 00:29:34.229990 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4946:tid 1401744768053 76] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sat Jul 22 00:42:05.642805 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10850:tid 140220855149 824] AH00489: Apache/2.4.57 (Ubuntu) configured – resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 22 00:42:05.642900 2023] [core:notice] [pid 10850:tid 140220855149824] AH00094: Command line: ‘/usr/sbin/apache2’
[Sat Jul 22 00:42:06.527493 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10850:tid 140220855149 824] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
```

is there anyway to fix this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: When you say that you “managed to clear some space”, how did you do that? From the look of the error messages, it seems that some core files have been deleted. The logs in `/var/log/mysql` will be useful to determine what’s wrong with your DB server 

Answer (score 0):

You somehow have managed to install both MariaDB and MySQL at the same time.

Look at the errors in:

`journalctl -u mysql.service -n 80`

and;

`journalctl -u mariadb.service -n 80`

It seems based on limited logs in the question, neither MySQL or MariaDB based on log error recognise the data sufficiently to start.

You'll need to restore the data back into a form that MySQL or MariaDB understand. I can't say how to do that without the logs of both. Please edit the `journalctl` information into your question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).